# use two jquery version in one page

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

Hi,

in page i use jquery 1.4.4 version, but one of my script request older versio.
I insert old jquery version and set new name:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var jq132 = $.noConflict(true);</script>
```

Then i get error on this line:

```
jq132("#docs_file ul").sortable({ opacity: 0.6, cursor: 'move', update: function()
```

Jus show(Firefox debuger): jq132("#docs_file ul").sortable is not a function

```
jq132(document).ready(function()
{   
    jq132(function()
    {
        jq132("#docs_file ul").sortable({ opacity: 0.6, cursor: 'move', update: function()
        {
            var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") + '&action=Listings'; 
            jq132.post("order.php", order, function(theResponse){
                jq132("#error").html(theResponse);
            });                                                              
        }                                 
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: The question shouldn't be "how to use two jQuery versions on the same page" but rather "how to I fix $ancient_broken_plugin to work with the newest jQuery version",

Comment: Fix "one of your script" instead. Trust me, it's the better way.

Comment: duplicate post http://stackoverflow.com/q/1566595/374804

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `noConflict` after including every plugin that you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

`sortable` is a plug-in, which means it will try to add itself to jQuery by assigning to the `jQuery.fn` object. So if you want to use plug-ins with the older jQuery, you'll have to load them before you rename `jQuery` and before you load the newer version of it. E.g.:

```
<script src='jquery132.js'></script>
<script src='some.plugin.js'></script>
<script>var jq132 = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
<script src='jquery144.js'></script>
<script src='some.plugin.js'></script>
```

Note that lines 2 and 5 are the same. The first one will add that script to jQuery 132. The second will add it to jQuery 1.4.4. Maybe. If the script doesn't have its own global symbols. If it doesn't assume `jQuery` will continue to reference jQuery (which is a fairly reasonable assumption for it to make).

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/eviha3)